# WebBrowser problem infinite loading

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I have one method. You can even test it:

```
 private readonly 
    public HtmlDocument Browse()
    {
        var _browser = new WebBrowser();
        var link = "http://hotline.ua/sr/?q=allo";
        var loadFinished = false;

        _browser.DocumentCompleted += delegate { loadFinished = true; };
        try
        {
            _browser.Navigate(link);
        }
        catch (Exception xx)
        {
            if (!(xx is UriFormatException))
                throw;

            loadFinished = false;
        }

        while ( ! loadFinished  )
            Thread.Sleep(50);

        loadFinished = false;

        return _browser.Document;
    }
```

Then somewhere in code I call this method:

```
var doc = Browse();
```

Instead of getting a HtmlDocument I get to the infinite loop in :

```
 while ( ! loadFinished  )
            Thread.Sleep(50);
```

It seems that DocumentCompleted is never fired. But in Web browser I can easily to get this page.
Anybody knows why ? And what should I do to get a HtmlDocument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh sorry. I found a solution, after I post this topic:

That the reason why this event not fired:

I should not use

```
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Because the event fired earlier and freed resourses. So thread get killed before it hits the document completed method.

If I change for:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

It becomes work perfectly.

Thanks for you replies also !

Answer (score 0):

You probably have exception which is not `UriFormatException` so the 
loadFinished is always false. Then `DocumentComplete` cannot be reached.
Put a break point in `Catch` in this line: `loadFinished = false;` and check what exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your delegate is correctly placed. You are not even taking the parameteres that this delegate needs. Take a look at:

[How to use WebBrowser control DocumentCompleted event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840813/how-to-use-webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-event-in-c)