# How to make WebBrowser wait till it loads fully?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a C# form with a web browser control on it.

I am trying to visit different websites in a loop.

However, I can not control URL address to load into my form web browser element.

This is the function I am using for navigating through URL addresses:

```
public String WebNavigateBrowser(String urlString, WebBrowser wb)
{
    string data = "";
    wb.Navigate(urlString);
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    data = wb.DocumentText;
    return data;
}
```

How can I make my loop wait until it fully loads?

My loop is something like this:

```
foreach (string urlAddresses in urls)
{
    WebNavigateBrowser(urlAddresses, webBrowser1);
    // I need to add a code to make webbrowser in Form to wait till it loads
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Attach a method to the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: OK! I did it like that because it helps me when I try to find something on stackoverflow

Comment: Brian, how can I do that thing? can u give me a sample line of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use webbrowser control DocumentCompleted event in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840813/how-to-use-webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-event-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add This to your code:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

Fill in this function

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
     //This line is so you only do the event once   
     if (e.Url != webBrowser1.Url) 
        return;


        //do you actual code        



    }
```

Comment: Sam, I cannot make my code run with your suggestion. It is not working

Comment: Note the `if` check which is *very* important. `DocumentedCompleted` will fire for each `iframe` as well, for instance.

Comment: Did you make sure to change webBrowser1 to wb?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? I know what I posted works with my code.

Comment: I need to run that code in a loop because there are numbers of URL. The code really works for the first loop but after the first loop it does not run. I have a HtmlElementCollection in which I am collecting some data out of visited website. In the first loop I can retrieve data for the collection however, in the second loop it does not make my code wait till the web page loads and thus, my collection is null and because of that my click event function does not work properly so the loop breaks. This is my problem. my click event handles if there is NEXT click available.

Comment: Thank you so much for this URL check!  I've been having problems with early DocumentCompleted fires for months and could not figure out why.

Comment: Finally a way that really works. My last one (while-loops and delays) was crap as hell. Thanks for this very very very much!

Comment: This will not fully work if there is complex javascript that builds content after the page load correct?

Answer (score 6):

After some time of anger of the crappy IE functionality I've came across making something which is the most accurate way to judge page loaded complete.

Never use the WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler event
use WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler with some modifections seen below.

//"ie" is our web browser object

```
ie.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(_ie);
private void _ie(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  int max = (int)Math.Max(e.MaximumProgress, e.CurrentProgress);
  int min = (int)Math.Min(e.MaximumProgress, e.CurrentProgress);
  if (min.Equals(max))
  {
   //Run your code here when page is actually 100% complete
  }
}
```

Simple genius method of going about this, I found this question googling "How to sleep web browser or put to pause"

Comment: Well... This did not help me with my javascript complete issue. :(

Comment: Confirming: this solution is not absolute. For example, this triggers for me 5 times, while `DocumentCompleted` only 2 times... So, that eternal question `"how to know when WB really finished loading document"` is still open.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) (contains sample source) you can use the `DocumentCompleted` event for that. Additional very helpful information and source that shows how to differentiate between event invocations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3050943/847363).

Comment: In practice it doesn't work. When I did it myself it triggers around 4-5 times for each Document.

Comment: @Haedrian it does work... it is called for every document that completes which means that it can be called several times for one URL (for example when it contains IFRAMEs or uses AJAX or works with redirections etc.). Follow the second link to see a suggestion on how to differentiate between these occurences...

Answer (score 0):

what you experiencend happened to me . readyStete.complete doesnt work in some cases.  here i used  bool in document_completed to check state

```
 button1_click(){
    //go site1 
    wb.Navigate("site1.com");
    //wait for documentCompleted before  continue to  execute  any further 
    waitWebBrowserToComplete(wb); 

    // set some values in html page
    wb.Document.GetElementById("input1").SetAttribute("Value", "hello");
    //  then click submit. (submit does navigation)
    wb.Document.GetElementById("formid").InvokeMember("submit");
    // then wait for doc complete        
    waitWebBrowserToComplete(wb);


    var processedHtml = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
    var rawHtml = wb.DocumentText;
}

// helpers
//instead of checking  readState . we get state from DocumentCompleted Event via bool value
bool webbrowserDocumentCompleted = false;
public static void waitWebBrowserToComplete(WebBrowser wb)
{
  while (!webbrowserDocumentCompleted )
      Application.DoEvents();
  webbrowserDocumentCompleted = false;
}

form_load(){
  wb.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) => {
     webbrowserDocumentCompleted = true;
  };
}
```