# Loop won't navigate my webbrowser VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim item As String

For Each item In Me.ListBox1.Items

    Wait(2000)

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(item)

    Wait(8000)

    Timer1.Start()
Next
```

I'm trying to make it navigate to each item

The wait(8000) works and the timer but the navigate won't

Comment: What is in `Me.ListBox1.Items`?

Comment: What is in your ListBox Items? EDIT: beat me to it :)

Comment: `item` is an `Object`.  Try `WebBrowser1.Navigate(item.ToString())`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something similar to this:
[How to make WebBrowser wait till it loads fully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776359/how-to-make-webbrowser-wait-till-it-loads-fully)

Basically you need wait for the document to finish loading before going to the next one.

Here is an example on microsoft website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1