# WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler is repeating itself

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to make a program that harvester data from a remote login site. I manage to log my self in but when i try to navigate through 2 pages my code makes the browser request and loads p1 then p2 then p1 then p2 and so on.

I try all methods within this link [How to make WebBrowser wait till it loads fully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776359/how-to-make-webbrowser-wait-till-it-loads-fully)

And it stills gives me the same problem!

Here is my code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(LookNew);
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Lookfind);

void LookNew(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Url != webBrowser1.Url)
    return;
  else
    FindLink(webBrowser1.DocumentText, "New").InvokeMember("Click");
}

void LookFind(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Url != webBrowser1.Url)
    return;
  else
    FindLink(webBrowser1.DocumentText, "find").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

Comment: I find it really hard to understand that

Comment: I trying to one event handler but putting all of my switch statement in this but i still have a problem.