# WebBrowser control has getting odd state

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use WebBrowser control DocumentCompleted event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840813/how-to-use-webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-event-in-c)

Could someone tell me why DocumentCompleted  event happens 3 times???

How do I know that document is REALLY has been downloaded?

(I used some pages to test that have a lot of jQuery.)

Thank you!

```
var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser
                {
                    Padding = new Padding(0),
                    Margin = new Padding(0),
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Url = url,
                    TabStop = false,
                    ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
                    IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false
                };
                webBrowser1.Navigated +=  (d1,d2) => 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Navigated " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
                };
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (d1, d2) => 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());                
                };


                form.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
                form.Show();
```

LOG:

Navigated 09:40:40.1807403
Navigated 09:40:44.7270004
DocumentCompleted 09:40:44.7300005
Navigated 09:40:46.5791063
DocumentCompleted 09:40:46.5821065
Navigated 09:40:50.1113083
DocumentCompleted 09:40:50.7133428
DocumentCompleted 09:40:50.7233433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good approach here

[How to use WebBrowser control DocumentCompleted event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840813/how-to-use-webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-event-in-c)

```
 webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (d1, d2) => 
                {


                    string urlCurrent = d2.Url.ToString();
                    var browser = (WebBrowser)d1;

                    if (!(urlCurrent.StartsWith("http://") || urlCurrent.StartsWith("https://")))
                    {
                        // in AJAX     
                    }
                    if (d2.Url.AbsolutePath != browser.Url.AbsolutePath)
                    {
                        // IFRAME           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // REAL DOCUMENT COMPLETE

                        Debug.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
                    }

                };
```